# Value format based on 1st Column value in select query in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table TableA as below

```
Channel      |  Column1 |  Column2 | Column3
---------------------------------------------
Channel1 %      10.20      10.30      15.50
Channel2        1000       10000      1000000
Channel3 %      5.10       8.50       12.45
Channel4        50000      3000       1500000
```

I want to develop select query to apply % sign next to value and K(thousand) and M(Millions) logic so that it return as below.

```
Channel      |  Column1 |  Column2 | Column3
---------------------------------------------
Channel1 %      10.20%      10.30%     15.50%
Channel2        1000        10K        1M
Channel3 %      5.10%       8.50%      12.45%
Channel4        50K         3000       1.5M
```

Comment: This looks like a major denormalisation issue. Formatting, however, should really be handled in the presentation layer, not the database layer.

Answer (score 1):

This is strange.  But assuming the values are strings, you can use `case` expressions:

```
(case when channel like '%$%' escape '$'
      then concat(column1, '%')
      when column1 >= 1000 and column1 < 1000000
      then concat(left(column1, len(column1) - 3), 'K')
      when column1 >= 1000000
      then concat(left(column1, len(column1) - 6), 'M')
      else column1
 end) as column1
```

Just repeat this logic for all the columns.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be a bit simpler than Gordon's logic, but the same idea:

```
CASE 
  WHEN RIGHT(channel, 1) = '%' THEN CONCAT(column1, '%')
  WHEN column1 >= 1000000 THEN FORMAT(column1/1000000.0, '0.#M')
  WHEN column1 >= 1000 THEN FORMAT(column1/1000.0, '0.#K')
  ELSE column1
END as column1
```

You might need some specific formatting depending on the number of decimal places you want in your K and M; you could `CONCAT(CAST(column1/1000.0 AS FLOAT), 'K')` but it's a bit of a cheat way to reduce the number of trailing 0 on a number. If your SQLS supports FORMAT like  `FORMAT(column1/1000.0, '0.#K')` you should consider using it instead

Answer (score 0):

You can use FORMAT function, but instead of hardcoding number, we can use like this. Though this kind of conversion should not be done at SQL Server and presentation application should handle this

```
SELECT
    Channel1,
      CASE 
        WHEN LEN(FLOOR(COL1)) <= 2 THEN CONCAT(COL1,'%')
        WHEN (LEN(FLOOR(COL1)) >= 4 AND LEN(FLOOR(COL1)) <=5) THEN FORMAT(COL1,'0,K')
        WHEN LEN(FLOOR(COL1)) >= 5 THEN CONCAT(COL1,'M') 
        END AS COL1,
      CASE 
        WHEN LEN(FLOOR(COL2)) <= 2 THEN CONCAT(COL2,'%')
        WHEN (LEN(FLOOR(COL2)) >= 4 AND LEN(FLOOR(COL2)) <=5) THEN  FORMAT(FLOOR(COL2),'0,K')
        WHEN LEN(FLOOR(COL2)) >= 5 THEN FORMAT(FLOOR(COL2),'M') 
        END AS COL2,
     CASE 
        WHEN LEN(FLOOR(COL3)) <= 2 THEN CONCAT(COL3,'%')
        WHEN  (LEN(FLOOR(COL3)) >= 4 AND LEN(FLOOR(COL3)) <=5) THEN   FORMAT(FLOOR(COL3),'0,K')
        WHEN LEN(FLOOR(COL3)) >= 4 THEN FORMAT(FLOOR(COL3),'0,,M')
        END AS COL3
FROM 
   TABLE
```